# Running c++ unittest using vstest.console.exe without visual studio installed

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

I copied the TestWindow folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow) to a machine that doesn't have visual studio installed and tried running the vstest.console.exe command on an x64 cpp test dll.

```
vstest.console.exe tests.dll /tests:testmethod1 /platform:x64 /logger:console
```

This is the error I see in the event log.

```
Application: vstest.discoveryengine.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Stack:
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestRunnerService.DataCollectors.DataCollectionPluginManager..ctor()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestRunnerService.WcfTestRunnerService..ctor(System.Threading.ManualResetEvent)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestRunnerService.TestRunnerServiceHost.CreateServiceHost(System.String, System.Threading.ManualResetEvent)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestRunnerService.ServiceMain.Main(System.String[])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `FileNotFoundException` was due to some required assemblies missing. I discovered these using WinDbg and copied them over to the TestWindow folder.

```
 - Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.Measurement.dll
 - Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.dll
 - Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common.dll
 - Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.ExecutionCommon.dll
 - Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Resource.dll
 - Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll
```

These assemblies can be found at `C:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL` on the machine that has visual studio installed.

I also noted that if I removed the `/tests` switch from the `vstest.console` command, these extra dlls were not required.

Also copied the following dlls to the TestWindow folder (to account for cases where the target machine doesn't have visual c++ runtime)

```
 - C:\Windows\System32\msvcr120.dll
 - C:\Windows\System32\msvcp120.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to having the TestWindow folder and the aforementioned GAC assemblies (ensure you have GAC assembly versions that match your version of Visual Studio) and the VSC++ assemblies if required, I also needed to ensure the latest version of the .NET Framework was installed.  I was working with VS 2012 vstest.console.exe and was able to run the help menu once I installed the .NET Framework 4.5.2 Windows Update.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution : just install [Visual Studio Agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/lab-management/install-configure-test-agents) on the server .

(In this case no need to copy/past the TestWindow folder.)